# Efficient way to implement IsAscii() in C#

Tags: c#, unicode, char, ascii

This is what I'm using right now, but I'm surprised why the CPU profiler shows this as a bottleneck while I have numerous other pretty expensive comparisons going on in my program.

```
private bool IsAscii(char c)
{
  return ((int)c < 128);
}
```

This function is used in a log processing program and therefore is called for every character in the log inside a tight loop. (but so are some other functions like Char.IsLetterOrDigit(), which do not seem to be as expensive).

I also tried few variations, with are all slightly slower than the one shown above or have similar performance. I wonder if I am doing something fundamentally wrong as I am new to C#.

Variations:-

```
// similar
private bool IsAscii(char c)
{
  return (c < 128);
}
```

--

```
// slower
private bool IsAscii(char c)
{
  return (Convert.ToInt32(c) < 128);
}
```

--

```
// similar
private bool IsAscii(char c)
{
  return ((c & (~0x7f)) == 0);
}
```

--

```
// slower
// class member
private char asciiend = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(128)[0];
private bool IsAscii(char c)
{
  return (c.CompareTo(asciiend) < 0);
}
```

--

Comment: What test case did you profile?  What does your profile code look like?  Incorrect assumptions when creating a controlled profiling environment sometimes lead to incorrect conclusions about speed of code blocks.

Comment: Did you try this in Release mode as well?

Comment: What happens if you manually inline the function?

Comment: I know it is an old question, but anybody visiting this: if you need `IsAscii` on a whole string, create a reference to the internal `String.IsAcii` function, for a char, use the private `Char.IsAscii` function. It is used in a lot of .NET's internals, good chance it'll perform well (I didn't test whether it outperforms your own code).

Answer (score 2):

For one thing, you might want to make it a static method. After all, it doesn't depend on state, and that *may* remove a nullity check. I would hope the JIT compiler's smart enough to see that it doesn't need it, but you never know.

Comment: @zmbq: Hmm... I'm sure that wasn't there when I first loaded the question... ah well, will remove...

Answer (score 1):

Try manually inlining it.  If that makes it faster, you might just need to manually inline it in the places where the call is a bottleneck.

Note that .NET Framework 4.5 introduces [`MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimploptions%28v=VS.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

My only guess is your function is not inlined by the jitter, so you spend most of the time on the function call, and not executing the function itself (which I really don't see how you can improve).

Try building the release build and add some home-made profiling (use a `Stopwatch`) to measure the time it takes you to go through a large log file. Run it without attaching it to Visual Studio (either from the outside, or by starting it with CTRL-F5). If my hunch is correct, you'll see that performance improve drastically, because the jitter will be free to inline away.

You can also instruct the jitter to perform its optimizations while running under the debugger. Switch to release build, go to Tools | Options | Debugging | General and uncheck "Suppress JIT optimization on module load".

And once you solve the performance issue, you really want IsAscii to be an extension method to the Char type - it makes more sense that way (but won't solve your performance problem)

Answer (score -1):

How about using [`Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.ascii.aspx) object from `System.Text`?

```
String ascii = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(originalString));
```

Though I'm not 100% sure I know what the intent is, or this is a viable option.

Comment: I doubt this will be faster than `((int)c < 128);` as it adds an extra layer of indirection.  The OP's primary concern is speed.